# winsql - Divide with the Rollup Value

Tags: winsql

I'm running the following Query:

select isnull(right(araccltid,4),'Tot') as ProdCode, count(aracid) as NumofAccounts
from araccount
where right(araccltid,4) between 5109 and 5112
group by right(araccltid,4) with rollup

using winSQL and it returns:

ProdCode  NumofAccounts
 5109       21864
5110    4206
5111    7380
5112    40075
Tot 73525

I would like to add a percentage column so that I see this:

ProdCode    NumofAccounts   Percentage
5109    21864   29.74
5110    4206    5.72
5111    7380    10.04
5112    40075   54.51
Tot 73525   100.00

I've tried adjusting the script as such:

select isnull(right(araccltid,4),'Tot') as ProdCode, count(aracid) as NumofAccounts, count(aracid)/tblCount.AcctCount as Percentage
from araccount, (select count(aracid) as AcctCount from araccount where right(araccltid,4) between 5109 and 5112) as tblCount
where right(araccltid,4) between 5109 and 5112
group by right(araccltid,4) with rollup

but I get this error:

Error: Column 'tblCount.AcctCount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (State:37000, Native Code: 1FB8)

Any help?